# Python NetworkX error: module 'networkx.drawing' has no attribute 'graphviz_layout'

Tags: python, nltk, graphviz, networkx

I am teaching myself Python and NLTK for work using the book "Natural Language Processing with Python" ("www.nltk.org/book").

I am stuck on Chapter 4 Section 4 part 8 on NetworkX.  When I try to run example 4.15, it should draw a graph, but instead I get the following error message:

> AttributeError: module 'networkx.drawing' has no attribute 'graphviz_layout'

The culprit code line appears to be

```
>>> nx.draw_graphviz(graph,
    node_size = [16 * graph.degree(n) for n in graph],
    node_color = [graph.depth[n] for n in graph],
    with_labels = False)
```

Here is simplified code borrowed from "networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/tutorial/tutorial.html"

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> G=nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node(1)
>>> G.add_nodes_from([2,3])
>>> nx.draw_graphviz(G)  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#92>", line 1, in <module>
    nx.draw_graphviz(G)
  File "C:\Users\Cheese\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 984, in draw_graphviz
    pos = nx.drawing.graphviz_layout(G, prog)
AttributeError: module 'networkx.drawing' has no attribute 'graphviz_layout'
>>>
```

Can you tell me how to fix this please?

I am on Windows 7 home premium, using Python 3.5, Graphviz2.38 (and the directory for that one is in the PATH environment variable), and NetworkX 1.11.

I have googled multiple times and can't find anything that works for me. I went through the NetworkX and graphviz tutorials and that didn't help either.

Here's what I found that didn't help:

"stackoverflow.com/questions/39411102/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-graphviz-layout-with-networkx" (answer code gave me the same error message)

"python.thenaiveapproach.com/buggy-module-installation-networkx-pygraphviz/" (per error message, requires pygraphviz, which I can't install. pip says it needs Visual C++ to run, and I can't install that on my work computer.)

"codedump.io/share/c3aAbCneu2oA/1/attributeerror-39module39-object-has-no-attribute-39graphvizlayout39-with-networkx-111" (Requires pygraphviz also -- see above)

Many thanks,
Jennifer

Comment: if you don't have pygraphviz (and also graphviz) installed, networkx can't draw graphs with this engine.  You could check whether other backends are sufficient for your purposes, including `draw_networkx`.

Comment: also note the opening paragraph in the [networkx drawing](http://networkx.readthedocs.io/en/networkx-1.11/reference/drawing.html) docs, which suggests using a dedicated plotting tool to draw graphs.  One way is to save the file in the relevant format and then use another tool to do the drawing externally.

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Here's what I did:  >>> nx.draw(G)
>>> plt.savefig("simple_path.png")
>>> plt.show()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is courtesy @Bonlenfum and code from https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/examples/drawing/simple_path.html

Here's the code that worked:

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> G=nx.Graph()
>>> G.add_node(1)
>>> G.add_nodes_from([2,3])
>>> nx.draw(G)
>>> plt.savefig("simple_path.png")
>>> plt.show()
```

And here's the adjusted code from the NLTK book:

```
try:
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
except:
    raise

def graph_draw(graph):
    nx.draw(graph,
         node_size = [16 * graph.degree(n) for n in graph],
         node_color = [graph.depth[n] for n in graph],
         with_labels = False)
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of an old question but I figured it worth mentioning for anyone looking:
simply change the method name from `draw_graphviz(..` to `draw_networkx(..`

Comment: It is not clear how this solves the problem. Please provide enough explanation and link to resources or additional documentation to support your answer.